# Inicar aplicacion existente de flutter en windows

Tags: windows, flutter, nuget

Estoy intentando correr una aplicación de flutter ya existente en Windows pero cuando lo ejecuto en debug me lanza el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna idea de como corregir el error anterior?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que he hecho para intentar corregir esto es descargar nuget.exe y establecerlo como variable de entorno y después agregar el siguiente código en el archivo CMakeList.txt

```
################ NuGet intall begin ################
find_program(NUGET_EXE NAMES nuget)
if(NOT NUGET_EXE)
    message("NUGET.EXE not found.")
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Please install this executable, and run CMake again.")
endif()

exec_program(${NUGET_EXE}
    ARGS install "Microsoft.Windows.CppWinRT" -Version 2.0.220224.4 -ExcludeVersion -OutputDirectory ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/packages)
################ NuGet install end ################

################ NuGet import begin ################
set_target_properties(${PLUGIN_NAME} PROPERTIES VS_PROJECT_IMPORT
  ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/packages/Microsoft.Windows.CppWinRT/build/native/Microsoft.Windows.CppWinRT.props
)

target_link_libraries(${PLUGIN_NAME} PRIVATE
  ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/packages/Microsoft.Windows.CppWinRT/build/native/Microsoft.Windows.CppWinRT.targets
)
################ NuGet import end ################
```

Answer (score 0):

Básicamente el error dice que es un ejecutable que hace falta en tu ordenador quizás lo tienes instalado o no has puesto las variables de entorno correctamente.

Lo puedes descargar desde aquí: https://www.nuget.org/downloads

En la lupa de búsqueda de windows busca "Variables de Entorno", quizás no sea necesario instalar Nuget.exe pero tu ordenador lo requiere, o bien falta algún archivo en la ruta en donde tienes guardado el sdk de Flutter (si funciona flutter doctor una vez que reinicias el sistema, está funcionando todo bien).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso sólo debes ingresar Nuget en el apartado de **Variables del sistema**. Este paso no es necesario en algunas versiones de windows, así que mira primero si están importadas las variables.

NOTA: Si es un proyecto que lo has probado anteriormente, fíjate en las dependencias, puede que alguna este **deprecated** o no sea compatible con Windows. También puede que el problema esté relacionado a VSCode, prueba si corre directamente en Android Studio, si es así, te sugiero reinstalar VSCode.